# Android widget stuck in "please login before using this widget" message

Tags: bug, android-app, android-app-widgets

The Android widget on my [Nexus 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nexus_5) is always saying:

> please login before using this widget

Here is a screenshot of this happening(sorry for the ugly style, I am not a great designer). I used blue rectangles to hide private/irrelevant information. I am trying to place the 2x1 widget in the 2x1 empty slot in the top right:

[image]

I have tried logging out and logging back in to the app, but still the problem persists.

This happened recently (in the past two months).

Comment: Can you post a screenshot please? Sounds like it's not the ordinary app. (It's not calling itself "widget" as far as I know.)

Comment: I would but i don't think it it's possible to take screenshot at that moment. Please note I am talking about the (for example 2*1) widget that I try to add to my home screen

Comment: @ShadowWizard I managed to grab a screenshot somehow and added it to the question. I don't thing it will help too much, though

Comment: Thanks, guess that's the best we can do, now need to wait for SE dev to take a look.

Comment: I can confirm this behavior. The previous version of the app (obtained from APKMirror) does not have the issue. Upgrading causes any existing widgets to stop functioning (they go blank) and you can't add new ones because of the aforementioned error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been fixed in version 1.0.93 which was released on 17 May, 2017.

It's very late, but better late than never.

**Edit:** When you try to add reputation widget on home screen, keep the stack exchange app open in background otherwise it will still give you same error.

**Edit 2:** The StackExchange App is de-listed from the play store.